# jquery $.each not appending to a string

Tags: javascript, jquery

I am playing around with extend.js and I am running into some issue with jQuery's `$.each` and appending to a string.

```
var Test = Class.extend(function(){
    this.dom = '<div ';
    this.class;
    this.id;

    this.add_class = function(){
        this.dom += 'class = "';
        $.each(this.class, function(i,e){
            console.log(e);
            this.dom += e;
            this.dom += ' ';
        });
        this.dom += '"';
        return this;
    };

    this.add_id = function(){
        this.dom += 'data-id = "'+this.id+'" ';
        return this.dom;
    };

});

var tester = new Test();
tester.class = ["coolClass", "TESTER"];
tester.id = "coolId";
console.log(tester.add_class().add_id());
```

Console shows

```
coolClass
TESTER 
<div class = "" data-id = "coolId"
```

I just can't see why my class is blank?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The `this` value gets reassigned to different things inside a `function` block. Check out

https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/this

You're going to need to do something like

```
    var that = this;
    $.each(this.class, function(i,e){
        console.log(e);
        that.dom += e;
        that.dom += ' ';
    });
```

Comment: Ohhhhhhhhhhhhhhhhh I knew i should go to bed. Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

Context.

Inside the $.each callback, `this` is the item that is currently being iterated through. it's not the `this` object that's `Test`.

Use this:

```
var oThis = this;
$.each(this.class, function(i,e){
    console.log(e);
    oThis.dom += e;
    oThis.dom += ' ';
});
```